# Static member variable in class with new operator

Tags: c++

Can I declare static data member using new in C++?
If we can declare static data member with new, how to initialize that static data member?

```
class A
{ 
    static int *p = new int;     
}

int * A :: p =
```

Comment: Declaration of the variable inline in the class, definition and initialization outside the class. That's the simplest.

Comment: that is fine , but my question is can i declare static variable using new in a class

Comment: no  don't think so ..as static values doesn't reside in heap

Comment: Yes. By having only the *declaration* inside the class definition. I.e. only `static int* p;`. Then define and *initialize* outside, i.e. `int* A::p = new int();  // Parenthesis for default initialization of the allocated memory`

Comment: However, what is the purpose of having a pointer to a single `int` value? Is it just an example?

Answer (score 6):

The way to go is to declare the variable inside the class and initialise it outside of it:

```
class A {
public:
  static int* anIntPointer; //<- declaration
};

int* A::anIntPointer = new int(42); //<- initialisation
```

However you would still need to clean up that memory manually since when the program ends only the pointer gets removed but the memory it points would still remain (unless your OS keeps track of the memory and cleans up after the program has ended). So call `delete A::anIntPointer`, e.g. at the end of `main`.

If you do have access to C++17 however you can declare the member `inline` wich allows you to directly initialise it.

```
class A {
public:
  inline static int* anIntPointer = new int(42); //<- declaration + initialisation
};
```

Anyway if you don't want to be responsible for cleaning up the memory yourself, you can use smart pointers ([`std::auto_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/auto_ptr) prior C++11, [`std::unique_ptr<>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr) C++11 and onward).

```
class A {
public:
  static std::unique_ptr<int> anSmartPointer;
};

std::unique_ptr<int> A::anSmartPointer = std::unique_ptr<int>(new int(42)); // C++11
// std::unique_ptr<int> A::anSmartPointer = std::make_unique<int>(42); // or C++14 style
```

When the `A::anSmartPointer` will be destroyed at the end of your program it cleans up the memory it controls automatically.

[***Here***](https://wandbox.org/permlink/oEux7zIaC9gizsPy) you can see working examples of all the things I just explained as well as a few other things (like a C++17 `inline static` smart pointer).

Comment: If it's C++11 or later sounds like a job for `std::unique_ptr<>` if earlier grit your teeth and use `std::auto_ptr<>` or roll your own.

Comment: Here pointer is static variable and data it points to is on heap, right?

Comment: @Viktor Correct.

Comment: @Persixty Thanks for the reminder. Added a short example.